# How can I give a script that reads input from a file input from stdin?

Tags: bash

I am working on a project that uses a script (blastn from NCBI's BLAST+ package) that, as far as I can tell, can only read input from a file. I'd like to be able to pass it a string in stdin and have it treat that as if it's the contents of a query file. I could do that by writing the string to a file then giving this script the name of a file but is there a different way to do it that I could try?

Comment: `/dev/stdin` is also a file

Comment: check https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 things come to mind:

- many tools (but not all) treat the filename `-` as "read from stdin"

  ```
  seq 20 | paste - -
  ```
- use a [Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution), that looks to the program like a filename

  ```
  rev <( echo "hello world" )
  ```